# Circle of infinite radius

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I've read a lot of content saying a circle of infinite radius is a line
And likewise that a plane has no boundary points

Now if I put the problem as such
Let $D(C,R)$ be the disk (open or closed) of center C and radius R

It's boundary is the circle of same center and radius

Now what is the boundary of this same disk when $R \rightarrow \infty$ ??

A disk of infinite radius is the whole plane and I think it's bringing me back to the original problem

Any explanation would be appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest looking into the hyperbolic plane, perhaps in the well-known upper half-plane model and disc model. In either case, the answer to your question is called a horocycle or horocircle. In particular, while one may also investigate various lengths, angles, and so on, there is a good deal that may be correctly drawn, without numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Hypercycles_and_horocycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a line, you need both $R \to \infty$ and $C$ goes to $\infty$.  For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, take $R > 0$ and $C = (R,0)$.  Then as $R \to \infty$, the boundary of $D(C,R)$ approaches the $y$ axis.